# how to add windows form in mfc application?

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, visual-c++, mfc

i wanna know how to add **windows form** to the MFC application (**Dialog-based**) and connect it with the MFC Dialogs,so i can program with visual c++ ?

Comment: "Windows Form" - do you mean the .Net ones?

Comment: I've added the applicable tags so people can find the question.

Comment: Still not really sure what you're looking for, here! Do you want to create Windows Forms (views) *entirely* in MFC, or are you looking to access forms created in .NET through an MFC/C++ program?

Answer (score -1):

http://www.functionx.com/visualc/Lesson04.htm

I think this is what you are looking for, hope this helps.

Comment: That's a good tutorial! Mohammad, please give some time to read and understand, that article will clear most of your doubts!

Comment: The article mentioned in this response does not say a thing about what is in the question, that is how to use .NET windows forms in a MFC app.

Answer (score -1):

The MFC class **CWinFormsControl** "provides the basic functionality for hosting of a Windows Forms control in a MFC application". 
One can encapsulate more Winform standard controls in a *.NET custom control* (derived from the System.Windows.Forms.Control class) and then use it in the MFC app through the  CWinFormsControl.

The MFC application must use the /clr flag (Common Language Runtime Support).